# Internal Server Error while uploading data to posts in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

While Uploading the data to Wordpress i am getting below error.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@domain.com and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

how to resolve this problem.?

Note: This error is only comes for only specific posts. Not for all posts.

Comment: @jeroen means, the error log of your http server (most probably is Apache), the file is called error.log inside `conf` folder of your server, or in folder of your script file

Comment: I try it.. Actually it's not recording any error log..
i tried to write error log..
but it's not logging..